# When is it ok to write literal in SystemVerilog without starting with something like 'b or 'd?

Tags: system-verilog

In my code I have this:

```
  localparam cntra_max = 10;
  localparam cntrb_max = 20;
```

This compiles just fine. This made me wonder, when is it ok to write a literal value like a natural number and when must it be written like 'd10, 'd20, 4'b1010 e.t.c?

Answer (score 2):

About the only place you *must* give a numeric literal an explicit width is as an operand inside a concatenation

`{32'd1, 32'd0}` inidcates your intent that you want a 64-bit value as a result as opposed to `{1,0}` which is illegal.

If you use a numeric literal without an explicit width, it is implicitly 32-bits wide. Your declaration become 32-bit signed parameters. If that is correct for the operations you plan to use them in, then you don't need to do anything else, but it is always better to be explicit about the datatypes to avoid hard to debug miscalculations.

```
localparam int unsigned cntra_max = 10;
```

Comment: I see, so it is possible to use normal integers without specifying width even with the logic and reg types?

Comment: It's possible for the simple expressions you show, but something like `~A-1` it makes a difference if the width of A is less than 32-bits.